# Cant set baseurl permanent in protractor

Tags: protractor

I run protractor like this

```
protractor  --params.env=q
```

q means QA. This protractor conf

```
  var CommonPageObject = require('./e2e/commonPageObject');


    suites: {
        login: './e2e/account/login/*.js'
},
 //for console params. example console command: protractor  --params.env=q
    params: {
            env: 'qa',//can be local, prod or qa default is qa for environment
    },
     onPrepare: function () {
            var commonPageObject = new CommonPageObject();
            commonPageObject.prepareVariables();


       }
```

this is common page

```
    this.prepareVariables = function () {console.log("xx",browser.params.env);
        var env = browser.params.env;
        this.setEnvironment(env);
        this.setBaseUrl(env);
    };
  //can be local, prod or qa. local = 2, qa = 0, prod=1
    this.setEnvironment = function (env) {
        if(env.includes("l")){
            environment = 2;
        }
        else{
            if(env.includes("p")){
                environment = 1;
            }
            else{// qa
                environment = 0;
            }
        }console.log("environment",environment);
    };

    //to get enviroment qa=0, prod=1, local=2 default=qa
    this.getEnvironment = function () {
        return environment;
    };

    this.setBaseUrl = function (env) {
        if(env.includes("q")){
            baseUrl = "http://xxxx.qa.xxx.com:8080";
        }
        else{
            if(env.includes("p")){
                baseUrl = "https://xxxxx.com";
            }
            else{
                baseUrl = "localhost:8080";
            }
        }console.log("baseUrl",baseUrl);
    };

    this.getBaseUrl = function () {console.log("getBaseUrl",baseUrl);
        return baseUrl;
    };
```

Output is thhat `protractor  --params.env=q`when i run

```
  xx q
environment 0
baseUrl http://xxx.qa.xxxx.com:8080
Started
getBaseUrl undefined
FgetBaseUrl undefined
F
```

it becomes undefined when tests starts. Whhy is that? Why commonpage object page variable cant be kept in stack? SO,, should i call those methods for each test inbefore each? Or am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your scope of the `commonPageObject` exists only within the context of the `onPrepare` method. This does not transfer to the rest of the spec files. What you should do is tie your `browserUrl` to a global variable. Protractor has one built in: `browser.baseUrl`

```
this.setBaseUrl = function (env) {
    if(env.includes("q")){
        browser.baseUrl = "http://xxxx.qa.xxx.com:8080";
    }
    else{
        if(env.includes("p")){
            baseUrl = "https://xxxxx.com";
        }
        else{
            baseUrl = "localhost:8080";
        }
    }console.log("baseUrl",baseUrl);
};

this.getBaseUrl = function () {console.log("getBaseUrl",browser.baseUrl);
    return browser.baseUrl;
};
```

Once your [browser.baseUrl](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/70bc6ea9c975604cf6facf73a4e855eb71ff4434/lib/cli.ts#L47) is set, in your spec files, you can now do `browser.get('/some/path');` which should resolve to `browser.baseUrl + '/some/path'`.